# Including two headers which are not available at the same time

Tags: c++, boost

There is a code repository including these two headers from [Boost](https://www.boost.org) library at the same time:

```cpp
#include <boost/nowide/cstdio.hpp> // => Not found with Boost 1_72_0
#include <boost/detail/endian.hpp> // => Not found with Boost 1_74_0 or 1_73_0
```

First I installed Boost `1_74_0` or `1_73_0` and the `<boost/detail/endian.hpp>` was not found. According to [this post](https://github.com/boostorg/endian/issues/45#issuecomment-664760174), I installed Boost `1_72_0`, the problem got resolved, but now `<boost/nowide/cstdio.hpp>` is not found!

I'm trying to figure out which Boost version to use to have **both headers**. I feel like I'm missing something, I appreciate any help =)

### SOLUTION

Using Boost `1_74_0` and:

- Replace `#include <boost/detail/endian.hpp>` with `#include <boost/predef/other/endian.h>`
- Replace `#ifndef BOOST_LITTLE_ENDIAN` with `#if BOOST_ENDIAN_BIG_BYTE`
- Replace `#ifdef BOOST_LITTLE_ENDIAN` with `#if BOOST_ENDIAN_LITTLE_BYTE`

Comment: Not sure but `boost/detail/endian.hpp` doesn't look like a public header.  Why do you include it?

Comment: Could it be your library needs Boost 1_73_0 ?

Comment: @rustyx Boost `1_73_0` cannot find `boost/detail/endian.hpp`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read [the `<boost/detail/endian.hpp>` header file](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/boost/detail/endian.hpp) it has a comment:

> `// Use the Predef library for the detection of endianess.`

Followed by

```
#include <boost/predef/detail/endian_compat.h>
```

It simply seems that the header you used have been obsolete or deprecated for a while, and finally removed.

So the solution is to migrate to the [Predef](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/predef/doc/index.html) library and its headers.

---

As for `<boost/nowide/cstdio.hpp>` it's part of the [Nowide](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/nowide/doc/html/index.html) library which was added with [Boost 1.73.0](https://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_73_0.html).